# How to set the second date picker's minimum date as first date picker's selected date in Odoo 10

Tags: datepicker, odoo

There are two date fields in a view, I want the user to select a time range, let's pretend the user picks 2016-06-06 in the first datepicker, is it possible to disable all dates previous to 2016-06-06 in the second datepicker?

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: Never thought that in that way, but you can handle it with constraints

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this module `web_widget_datepicker_options`.

`<field name="date" options="{'datepicker': {'minDate': '2018-09-01'}}"/>`